# How to initialize a memory allocation to 1s?

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

```c
a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N); 
b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

If I have allocated some memory, how do I initialize both a and b to 1's ?

Comment: Casting the result of `malloc()` is frowned upon ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @pmg I was just thinking of that myself (see edited answer) - while I was taking a bath! I normally point it out (and have done in most of my other relevant posts).

Comment: As you have the `cuda` tag, maybe worth considering `cuMemAlloc()`, in which case you can then use `cuMemsetD32()` on the memory block.

Comment: @pmg  if you want your code to compile with a C++ compiler, a cast is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no *standard* way of initializing a memory block (of non-byte-size data) to anything other than all zeros without using a loop. (For *all zeros*, you can use the [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) function; and, for a block of *single-byte* values, you can use ['memset()'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset))

In your case, as the two blocks are the same size, and you want to initialize both to the same values, you can use a simple, one-line loop:

```c
a = malloc(sizeof(int)*N); // No need to cast the return value of malloc!
b = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
// Initialize:
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) a[i] = b[i] = 1;
```

There are various 'tricks' you might consider to optimize the `for` loop, but such practices are risky, platform-specific hacks, and often achieve very little in terms of execution speed. Further, most modern compilers will make short-shrift of that loop, using techniques such as loop unrolling, vectorization and CPU-specific intrinsics (`MSVC`, for example, generates code to use a 64-bit integer with a value of `0x0000000100000001` to cut the number of loops in half).

---

On not casting the result of `malloc`, see: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)